# how do ListViews know which view belongs to a specific AsyncTask thread

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I have read through the following [article](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html), it explained how a listView works, sometimes a view launches a asyncTask Thread, if the bitmap is not found in the lruCache/diskCache. But then that view gets recycled. Therefore when the asyncTask is finished, how does it know which view to populate ? is there a simple sample project you could also guide me to ?

Comment: Did you post the right link? It does not talk about `ListView`s rather than caching bitmaps. The mentioned async task does not care about any list views.

Comment: if you read more, it will talk about list views, i think on the next page

Answer (score 0):

The async task always tries to populate the view which you supplied as parameter. So when the screen orientation changes and the activity gets recreated the task may or may not finish decoding bitmap (depending on how far you read the turorial) but it will not show the image. Once the activity recreates  a new async task will be started to load the image.

Answer (score 0):

The recycled view is still there (as it is recycled). As long as you don't tell the AsyncTask that it should not populate to the now recycled view, it will show the wrong image in the view.

You need to implement an AsyncTask with a cancel mechanism that informs the AsyncTask that it should not populate anymore (or you null the reference to the view in the task and you check for null there).

Picasso, an image loading library, has a method that cancels previews requests for a view as soon as you create a new request which is basically what happens when you scroll within a listview and your view gets recycled.